# NoSuchMethodError with SparkContext

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark

I get a `NoSuchMethodError` when my Spark application executes `val sc = new SparkContext("spark://spark01:7077", "Request Executor")`. I am compiling my Spark application with version 1.3.1 and Scala version 2.10.4. The Spark cluster is compiled with 1.3.1 as well as the same Scala version.

From looking at the Spark source, `getTimeAsSeconds` does not exist in `Utils.scala` until Spark 1.4. Why is it attempting to call a method that does not exist in the version I'm using?

Here are the dependencies from my `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
  <artifactId>spark-core_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-compiler</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>scala-reflect</artifactId>
  <version>2.10.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.twitter</groupId>
  <artifactId>util-eval_2.10</artifactId>
  <version>6.26.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
  <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
  <version>19.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2_commons</groupId>
  <artifactId>jaxb2-basics-runtime</artifactId>
<version>0.7.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- Jackson JSON Library -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.module</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-module-jaxb-annotations</artifactId>
  <version>2.4.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.woodstox</groupId>
  <artifactId>woodstox-core-asl</artifactId>
  <version>4.1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>uk.org.simonsite</groupId>
  <artifactId>log4j-rolling-appender</artifactId>
  <version>20131024-2017</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.12</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-server</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.1.v20150714</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.1.v20150714</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
  <artifactId>jetty-webapp</artifactId>
  <version>9.3.1.v20150714</version>
</dependency> 

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
  <artifactId>antlr4-runtime</artifactId>
  <version>4.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
  <artifactId>solr-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
      <artifactId>jetty-util</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

Is something in my dependencies causing me to compile with Spark 1.4?

Stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.spark.network.util.JavaUtils.timeStringAsSec(Ljava/lang/String;)J
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.timeStringAsSeconds(Utils.scala:1027)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkConf.getTimeAsSeconds(SparkConf.scala:194)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.org$apache$spark$util$AkkaUtils$$doCreateActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:68)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$$anonfun$1.apply(AkkaUtils.scala:53)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$1.apply$mcVI$sp(Utils.scala:1991)
        at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:166)
        at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:1982)
        at org.apache.spark.util.AkkaUtils$.createActorSystem(AkkaUtils.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcEnvFactory.create(AkkaRpcEnv.scala:245)
        at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:52)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:247)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:188)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:267)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:424)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:155)
        at com.scala.analytics.RequestExecutor$.executeRequest(RequestExecutor.scala:23)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:735)
        at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:848)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:816)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doHandle(ServletHandler.java:583)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doHandle(ContextHandler.java:1113)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.doScope(ServletHandler.java:511)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doScope(ContextHandler.java:1047)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ScopedHandler.handle(ScopedHandler.java:141)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:119)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server.handle(Server.java:517)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpChannel.handle(HttpChannel.java:302)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpConnection.onFillable(HttpConnection.java:242)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.AbstractConnection$ReadCallback.succeeded(AbstractConnection.java:238)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.FillInterest.fillable(FillInterest.java:95)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.io.SelectChannelEndPoint$2.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:57)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.produceAndRun(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:213)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.strategy.ExecuteProduceConsume.run(ExecuteProduceConsume.java:147)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool.runJob(QueuedThreadPool.java:654)
        at org.eclipse.jetty.util.thread.QueuedThreadPool$3.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:572)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you please check which JAR is used when you're running your application? It looks like your spark is indeed 1.4.0. if you're using Linux use `find . -name *.jar | grep assembly` (if you compiled yourself the code it should be under `./assembly/target/scala-xxx`)

Comment: My spark jar is: `spark-assembly-1.3.1-hadoop2.6.0.jar`.

Comment: Where did you get the source code from? directly from github or from the website? Can you please show the command you used to compile Spark?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out it was a dumb mistake. I am running this application on a different machine, so I copy over my target directory every time I compile. However, I never cleaned my target directory on the remote machine, so I had an old jar with Spark 1.4.0 sitting there, which I used at one point. Every time my application ran, it would look for a Spark jar and use the 1.4.0 jar instead of the 1.3.1 jar that's also in the directory. The solution was simply to delete the old (1.4.0) jar.